# FB.Event.subscribe not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe

I have a popup box to like a facebook page. I need to remove this iframe popup once the like button is pressed, so i tried using `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ...` but this event is not firing, am I missing something?

```
function popup() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'my app ID',
                authResponse: false,
                channelUrl: "my channelUrl",
                cookie: true,
                oauth: true,
                status: true,
                xbfml: true
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

            function (response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',

            function (response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            });
        };
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    });

    function makingdifferent_ppopup() {
        var mdwh = jQuery(window).height();
        var mdpph = jQuery("#makingdifferentpopup").height();
        var mdfromTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 50;
        jQuery("#makingdifferentpopup").css({
            "top": mdfromTop
        });
    }
    jQuery(window).fadeIn(makingdifferent_ppopup)
        .resize(makingdifferent_ppopup)
    var mdleftm = 500;
    jQuery("#makingdifferentpopup").animate({
        opacity: "1",
        left: "0",
        left: mdleftm
    }, 0).show();
    jQuery("#mdclose").click(function () {
        jQuery("#makingdifferentpopup").animate({
            opacity: "0",
            left: "-5000000"
        }, 1000).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any error shown in Developer Console?

Comment: no there is no errors

Comment: first of all: don´t annoy people with a like popup. like gating is not allowed anyway ;) - that being said, where do you call the popup function and why are you using the document ready function inside that popup function?

Comment: Do you have a live example page we can look at? Note: You should include the JavaScript SDK code (`(function (d, s, id) {` just under the opening body tag and not in document.ready.